# Erro pra executar um map no JS: react-refresh-runtime.development.js:315 Uncaught TypeError: todo.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, react, firebase

Estou usando o react junto com o firestore, e estou buscando os dados do db colocando dentro de todo, mas quando eu tento fazer um todo.map acontece esse erro dizendo que o todo.map não é uma função.
estou dando um console.log no getTodoList pra garantir que sim, está retornando um array do meu db...

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { db, doc, getDocs, collection, addDoc, deleteDoc } from "./firebase";

function App() {
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState("");

  // Dar entrada em uma nova mercadoria
  async function newProduct(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  // Deletar uma Mercadoria
  async function deleteProduct(id) {
    const productDoc = doc(db, "toDo", id);
    await deleteDoc(productDoc);
  }

  // Buscar os dados dentro da coleção
  useEffect(() => {
    const toDoCollectionRef = collection(db, "toDo");
    const getTodoList = async () => {
      const data = await getDocs(toDoCollectionRef);
      const toDoList = data.docs.map((doc) => ({
        ...doc.data(),
        id: doc.id,
      }));
      setTodo(toDoList);
      console.log(toDoList);
    };
    getTodoList();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Lista de Mercadoria</h1>
      <form>
        <input type="text"></input>
        <button>Add</button>
        <ul>
          {todo.map((li) => {
            return <li key={li.id}>{li.todo}</li>;
          })}
        </ul>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Fala Luis,

Tente inicializar o `todo` com `[]` ao invés de `""`. Creio que esse erro aconteça porque uma string não contém o método `map`. A variável `todo` só se torna um array depois que os dados do banco são retornados, o que é um processo assíncrono. Antes que você tenha os dados, o react já tentou dar o render e por isso o erro acontece.

Comment: É isso mesmo, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: se puder votar como certa, fico agradecido (=

Comment: desculpa, aqui está dizendo que nao tenho reputação... só com 15 pontos